# if first condition is true , assign a value to a variable in javascript , Reference error invalid assignment left hand side

Tags: javascript

I am trying to do this.

```
index==5&&index=6;
```

index is a variable defined and if it has a value of 5, it should be assigned  a value 6 , but it is giving a error ReferenceError: invalid assignment left-hand side , this works in php .I know alternate ways to do it but what is the reason behind this behaviour

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just about [precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence). Use parenthesis:

```
index&&(index=6);
```

The fact this isn't obvious is an important reason to avoid this trick. Prefer a good old `if` so that any human can immediately parse your code (code quality tools will warn you about this one).

Answer (score 2):

but it is not good style.

```
index == 5 && (index = 6);
```

Answer (score 2):

The assignment operator `=` has very low operator precedence. Your expression is therefore parsed as

```
(index == 5 && index) = 6
```

You can parenthesize the assignment operator:

```
index == 5 && (index = 6);
```

You could also rewrite the statement so that a programmer in the future can more easily understand your intention:

```
if (index == 5) index = 6;
```

The easy way to check operator precedence is to look at the spec. Lower-precedence operators are described further down in the spec than higher-precedence operators. There's also [this handy table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) at the Mozilla site.